# Booting Debian 10 Buster from Raspberry Pi 4B USB3.1 device

Tags: usb, pi-4, boot-issues, debian

I have followed [this YT video guide](https://youtu.be/a8nzkLryGmM) to be able to boot from a USB device on a Raspberry Pi 4B. It worked perfectly from my USB flash drive (#1) running Raspberry Pi OS. However, when I swapped out the USB flash drive for one which has Debian 10 Buster on it (#2), this second USB flash drive failed to boot, with the following error...

```bsh
Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
done.
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat proc/modules: ls /dev)
ALERT! LABEL=RASPIBOOT does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Debian 1:1.30.1-4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Now it seems that my Raspberry Pi EEPROM can handle USB booting (as it boots USB flash drive #1), but the specific USB flash drive (#2) which I have prepared with Debian 10 Buster on won't boot. It seems that it isn't enough just to update the EEPROM on the raspi device to get this working, I also need to update the individual USB flash drives as well. Is this right? If so, how do I do that for an OS on first boot? Is there a difference for this procedure under Debian 10 as opposed to Raspberry Pi OS? Do I need to create a Debian 10 sd-card, and follow the same (or similar) procedure on it as I did for the Raspberry Pi OS one, copying from the Debian 10 sd-card to the Debian 10 USB flash drive?

Comment: I'm still trying to resolve this myself, but it is like swimming through molasses. It's like learning everything from the start again. At first I couldn't even login to the Debian system, as the default username and password is different than for Raspbian. Now I find there is no **`raspi-config`** (nor even the **`sudo`** command) under Debian. Unfortunately I need Debian, not Raspbian, in order to be able to install the latest YunoHost v4.3.4.2.

Comment: I've been chatting with **`@Tenkawa`** on the #raspberrypi channel on Libera.chat IRC about this. They say that this is a very specific Raspberry Pi 4 / 400 issue, and that Debian 10 Buster is difficult to run on these devices. I'm now waiting to hear back from the YunoHost team, to see if Debian is absolutely necessary, or if I can get away with Raspbery Pi OS 10 instead. Any advice from here on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have just heard back from the YunoHost dev team...

> *"My very, very, bad. I mistyped or somehow forgot you were on Raspberry. You need Raspbian 10/Buster image, not pure Debian, to be sure all the appropriate software are installed."*

So, back I go to installing YunoHost v4.1.7.2, which is bundled with Raspbian already, then I can do the upgrade to v4.3.4.2 afterwards. It is messy, but is the only way to do it, apparently. Sorry for wasting people's time here.